# esp32 AWS iot connection issue on certain wifi router

Tags: esp32, aws-iot

I am working on connecting the esp32 to aws iot using esp-idf.

My project was working properly without big issue. However, I found that the esp32 connected to aws iot can only keep the connection for less than one minute today. It then repeat disconnecting and reconnecting.
The log output show "aws_iot: failed! mbedtls_ssl_handshake returned -0x6800" when esp32 is disconnected

I have tried to connect the esp32 to another wifi and it work properly. Therefore, I guess the wifi may be a factor. However, the wifi that the esp32 connected with a problem seem normal. My desktop and mobile phone can access the network properly when they are connected to this wifi.

I will be grateful if anyone can give me some advice to resolve this issue.

This problem is first seen today.

Comment: Maybe your router has an aggressive timeout mechanism? Have you try to reduce the keep alive interval to something around 15s?